# Populate a separate div for button clicks where button id is based on variables

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, populate

I currently have a table populated with MySQL data like so:

```
 $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM artist LIMIT 10");
if (!$result) {
    printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($con));
    exit();
}




      //show artist data in table
       echo "<table><th>BadNoise Artists</th>";
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
          {
          echo "<tr><td>" . $row['FirstName'] . "</td><td>" . $row['LastName'] . "</td><td><button id='" . $row['ArtistNumber'] . "'>Songs by this artist</button></tr>" ;
          }
 echo "</table>";
 mysqli_close($con);
```

?>

The script in the header tells each button click to populate the same div:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
       var ArtistNumber = $(this).attr('id');
    $("#div1").load("demo_test" + ArtistNumber + ".txt");
  });
});
</script>
```

What I need to be able to do is put a div in each row of the table for each result and to have that row's button populate that row's div when clicked

Comment: maybe if you showed what your actual desired html looks like...

Comment: Could we get a little more clarification? What is this `div` you are talking about?

Comment: To be honest I haven't got to structuring the HTML. I am new to PHP/AJAX and just trying to get the functionality down first. Let me tell you exactly what my brief says: "The button supports an AJAX enabled 'onclick' handler that is subsequently used to add song related content to the page. To support this requirement, each entry must contain an empty div element. This div is dynamically populated with a set of links that target the songs made available by that artist, when the user clicks on the button. The content is inserted into the div by the AJAX callback function".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I know what you are trying to do. What you want is a div in each row that gets populated when you click the button. So your PHP code would look like this:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tr><td>" . $row['FirstName'] . "</td>
<td>" . $row['LastName'] . "</td>
<td><button id='" . $row['ArtistNumber'] . "'>Songs by this artist</button></td>
<td><div id='artist" . $row['ArtistNumber'] . "'></div></td></tr>" ;
}
```

And you would change your JQuery to put it in that `div` using its id:

```
$("#artist" + ArtistNumber).load("demo_test" + ArtistNumber + ".txt");
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you, this works! But for some reason, it opens up a blank javascript alert every time I click any of the buttons...

Comment: Don't worry, fixed that. Thanks again.

Comment: I tried but my rep isn't high enough :( (I've only been on here a little while) Sorry!

Comment: Oh well. Glad to help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to add a div to each row of your table. You can give it a class of "results". Then refer to it in your JS. This is what I would do:

HTML/PHP:

```
<body>
    <?php

      //$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM artist LIMIT 10");
      if (!$result) {
      printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($con));
      exit();
      }

      //show artist data in table
      echo "<table><th>BadNoise Artists</th>";
      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
          ?>
          <tr>
              <td><?= $row['FirstName']; ?></td>
              <td><?= $row['LastName']; ?></td>
              <td><button id="<?= $row['ArtistNumber']; ?>">Songs by this artist</button></td>
              <td><div class='results'></div></td>
          </tr>
          <?php
      }
      echo "</table>";
      mysqli_close($con);
    ?>
</body>
```

JS:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("button").click(function() {
            alert();
            var ArtistNumber = $(this).attr('id');
            $(this).closest("tr").find(".results").load("demo_test" + ArtistNumber + ".txt");
        });
    });
</script>
```